# Find the length of overalp in lists with binary values

Tags: python, arrays, list

Assuming I have these two lists:

```
a = [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]

b = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
```

I would like to know the number of times the number 1 appears in the same position, in this case it would be 5

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: You can and the two lists and then count the ones in the result.

Comment: Haven't been able to think of anything yet... The suggestion is for a similar question, but they want the values that appear in both lists, here I'm trying to obtain the number ov values that are the same and in the same position

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“I can't think of anything” is an issue for local tutelage in problem analysis, not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Use bitwise operators and zip:

```
sum([x&y for x,y in zip(a,b)])
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I was suggesting in my comment.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]

b = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]

result = np.logical_and(np.array(a), np.array(b))

print(np.count_nonzero(result == True))
```

Answer (score -2):

Make the sum of the two lists then see if the result of each cell is 2 (1 + 1):

```py
a = [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]

b = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]

sum = [] # sun of the two lists
for x in range(len(a)):
    sum.append(a[x] + b[x])

_1_in_both = []
for x in range(len(sum)):
    if sum[x] == 2: # sum[x] == 2 <==> 1 in both lists
        _1_in_both.append(x)

print('1 occurs in both lists', len(_1_in_both), 'times, in positions', _1_in_both)
```

Output:

> 1 occurs in both lists 5 times, in positions [4, 5, 6, 10, 11]